# after installing: pip install ffn, importing ffn failed

Tags: python, installation, pip

I am getting the below error after installing ffn, then importing ffn:

```py
201 @utils.memoize
202 def get(tickers, provider=None, common_dates=True, forward_fill=False,
203         clean_tickers=True, column_names=None, ticker_field_sep=':',

NameError: name 'utils' is not defined
```

Comment: `from ffn import utils` or `@ffn.utils.memoize`

Comment: Thanks. I did below: but still got the same error. "from ffn import utils" same error message: name 'tils' is not defined.

Comment: Import ffn -- it worked all the time.  it just started to have this error messages today, don't know what happened?  can't import ffn.